# Structure of "c'hai"

Tags: grammar, orthography

When using `ci` as a demonstrative pronoun it replaces the object completely, for instance: *Sei mai uscito con la mia sorella? Non, non `ci` sono mai uscito*, so in the answer there is no information about the object (gender, quantity, etc), but everything is absorbed by `ci`. Now, if we say

> *noi pregheremmo lui de la tua pace,
> poi `c'hai` pietà del nostro mal perverso.*

1. Is `c'hai` a valid contraction of `ci hai`? and
2. if we use `ci` then shouldn't we suppress the object to avoid redundancy? That is, isn't *poi c'hai pietà* enough, or *poi hai pietà del nostro mal perverso* enough?

Comment: I suspect in this particular case, it is a contraction of *che hai* (with *poi che* as an archaic form of the more normal *poiché*). But I'm not 100% sure, it's just how I always read that verse

Comment: I agree with @DenisNardin. For 99% of the history of Italian language, “c'hai” has been the contraction of “che hai”. Using it for “ci hai” is a recent and debatable development.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way of reading the words is *poi c'hai pietà del nostro mal* is *poi che hai pietà del nostro mal*. In modern Italian, the first two words are more often written as a single one, *poiché*, meaning “since, due to”. Hence, the clause means simply something like “...since you have mercy on our wicked suffering” (not an actual nice translation, since English is not my mother tongue).

Out of curiosity, this is how the sentence appears in Dorothy L. Sayers's translation of Dante's *Comedy*:

> ...we would entreat Him for thy peace,
> That pitiest so our pangs dispiteous!

Notice that for 99% of the history of Italian language, *c'hai* has been the contraction of *che hai*, as here. Using it for *ci hai* is a recent and debatable development.

Comment: Just as  confirmation of what it's said in this answer. This sentence comes from the *canto V* of *Inferno* of Dante's *Comedy* (the famous *canto* of Paolo and Francesca), so it's indeed archaic Italian. And, for instance (I'm sure there are tons of paraphrasis), it's paraphrased in this way by Claudio Giunta in his book *Cuori intelligenti. Mille anni di letteratura. Dalle origini al Rinascimento*: "noi lo pregheremmo per la pace del tuo spirito, poiché hai pietà della nostra terribile sofferenza".

Comment: Curiously, this verse appears in a quotation in the entrance [*poiché*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI13/00731.jpg) of the *Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*, but with the alternative spelling "poi ch'hai".

Comment: Ah, interesting, @Charo, but if I see correctly both Petrocchi and Sapegno have "c'hai". (You're probably aware that there are no manuscripts of the Comedia in Dante's own hand, so philologists have to use various later copies to reconstruct backwards the most reliable "original" version).

Comment: Yes, @DaG: in fact, all the editions of the *Inferno* I own have "c'hai", sometimes spelled "c' hai".